# How much reduction of hyperparameter experiments can I get using Bayesian optimization vs Grid search?

Tags: hyperparameter, bayesian-optimization

I have 5 hyperparameters for tuning and the number of combinations of all possible values is 9,360. This means if I want to find the optimal parameter setting using Grid Search, I need to do 9,360 experiments. When I use Bayesian Optimization for this task, I need to specify how many experiments to run. Therefore, I would like to get some idea about how much reduction Bayesian Optimization can offer.

Comment: It's not possible to know this. You should experiment with it.

Comment: It's going to be highly problem specific.